# Html bottom textarea move up too high when the keyboard pop up in iPhone

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I'm developing a chat app in javascript, and the chatbox placed in the bottom of the body, but when I visit my html page, pressed the input element, the textarea always move up too high, so the input element always leave a small gap with the keyboard, I wan to know how to fix this problem, thx. ^_^

Current:

[image]

But I want the following effect:

[image]

Anyone meet this problem, and how to fix it (sorry for my poor English)

Comment: post a fiddle or your code here please :)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried in margin-bottom: 0%; in css?